# How to make ctrl+c in Linux bash terminal behavior look like OSX terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

In OSX terminal when there is a running process ctrl+c will terminate it, but when there is no process running ctrl+c will copy text.

Is it possible to do the same on linux terminal,
And bind multiple actions to the same shortcut?

Comment: If you want to copy text, you can use ctrl+shift+c

Comment: You could remap your keys, options here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66970/remap-ctrlc-ctrlv-and-ctrl-x-only

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `command+c`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know this is worked but i want to know are there any way to use the same keyboard shortcut to do different action base on the condition.